# Using Soundcloud player buttons to change elements on the page embedded on

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

specifically, I will have 5 soundcloud tracks/sets on a single html page. When one of these is played, I would like to change the background image of the page the player is embedded on to compliment the artwork on the player (but a different image).

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the Widgets API provided by SoundCloud:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

I imagine you will use the bind function to bind to the play event. Something like:

```
 widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY , function() {
     console.log('Playing... Update CSS here');
 });
```